# How do I sum elements of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to python and this is already the second question I ask here. I have the following pandas dataframe obtained from an API:

```
                              data                metadata                                    
1388534400000        {'electricity': 0.0}            NaN                                    
1388538000000        {'electricity': 0.0}            NaN                                    
1388541600000        {'electricity': 0.0}            NaN                                    
1388545200000        {'electricity': 0.0}            NaN                                    
1388548800000        {'electricity': 0.0}            NaN
```

These are only the first elements of the dataframe (columns 'data' and 'metadata'), the last lines are these:

```
1420066800000  {'electricity': 0.0}            NaN                               
params              NaN                      {'lat': '51.564', 'lon': ...
units               NaN                      {'time': 'UTC', 'electricity': 'kW'}
```

I had python print the type of structure and it returned this:

I want to get the sum of all the float values that come after 'electricity' but don't know how. I have searched on google and couldn't find anything that works. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

This is how I'm requesting the data:

```py
def query_pv(lat, lon, date_from, date_to, 
         tilt, azim=180, tracking=0, system_loss=10, 
         capacity=1, dataset='merra2', interpolate=False, 
         local_time=False, raw=False):

s = requests.session()

# get token
token = _load_token()

# send token through header
s.headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + token}

url = API_BASE + 'data/pv'

# pre-process inputs
date_from = _date_to_string(date_from)
date_to   = _date_to_string(date_to)

args = {
    'lat': lat,
    'lon': lon,
    'date_from': date_from,
    'date_to': date_to,
    'dataset': dataset,
    'capacity': capacity,
    'system_loss': system_loss,
    'tracking': tracking,
    'tilt': tilt,
    'azim': azim,
    'format': 'json',
    # 'metadata': metadata,
    'raw': raw
}

r = s.get(url, params=args)

if not r.ok:
    raise Exception('Query failed. Check input parameters.')

return pd.read_json(r.text, orient='index')
```

Comment: So you have Json inside your dataframe ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean but the dataframe was created from a json file.

Comment: the data column, it is presenting the data inside as a dict ?

Comment: Yes, it is @Mayeulsgc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your data through an apply to get the sum column-wise :

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [{'electricity':0.0},{'electricity':1.0},{'electricity':5},{'electricity':4}],'B':['a','b','a','c']})
sumElectricity = df['A'].dropna().apply(lambda x: x['electricity'])).sum()
```

This approach however implies that every row is either null or has a dict with a `electricity` key.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I apologise for taking so long to reply but I had issues with the PyCharm debugger and was only able to test this today. Thank you!